How can we calculate the Integral of a vector norm along a parametrized line?
I feel a bit silly because I've been trying to calculate the following integral and I believe that the solution is likely extremely easy, but I am blanking. Let $p \in (0,1)$, Given two vectors $\xi$ and $\eta$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, I want to calculate the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{1} | \xi + t\eta |^{2p} dt. $$
Where $|\xi+t\eta|$ is just shorthand here for the 2-norm, not the absolute value. I recognize that geometrically this is just starting at some point in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and following a line in the $\eta$ direction and integrating the norm along that line. I've tried to rewrite this as
$$ \int_{0}^{1} ((\xi + t\eta)\cdot(\xi+t\eta))^{p}~dt $$
$$ \int_{0}^{1} (|\xi|^2 + 2t(\xi\cdot\eta) + t^2|\eta|^2)^{p} ~dt. $$
which led me down a rabbithole of trying to integrate quadratics which dont seem to have a nice (general) form. I have tried to rethink this as some form of substitution, but traditional techniques I do know from calculus do not seem to work. For example, attempting a 'u-substitution' of sort with $u = \xi + t \eta$ yields that $du = \eta dt$, which certainly is not helpful given its a vector valued quantity. Are integrals like this known? I seem to not find results searching up the title of this post.

Do you have any reason to expect there’s anything to do other than to expand by the trinomial theorem?

@TedShifrin Here, $p$ will be a constant in the interval $(0,1)$ because this integral arose in the context of the fractional Laplacian.

Yes, I don't think there is anything better to do than just trinomial expansion here.
